# How to get alexa to give the best fact from an array

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to build off of the alexa fact skill (space facts) but I don't want to give a randomized response

rather than creating multiple intents for every answer is there a way to have alexa parse the responses and give the best fact for the question? (either an array of responses or a spreadsheet with utterance and response possibly?)

Thank you!

Comment: How do you provide a best fact, when a user ask for some fact? You can be more elaborate in your question with some sample utterances.

Answer (score 0):

Create a slot in your facts intent, slots are the part that is going to change.
See this example with planets:
https://gist.github.com/germanviscuso/b9d9efd5d15a7907e1d2e4ada1fa65d6#file-es-mx-json-L39
(in Spanish, sorry)
Then based on the slot value you search your data with the slot value as filter and provide the best answer